# vscode debugger cannot correcly locate Rust source code when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-debugger

issue description: vscode debugger cannot correclt locate Rust source code when debugging. When I type "F11" at line 9, it popups error message at right bottom corner

platform: windows 10

rust active toolchain: stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)

rust version: rustc 1.43.1 (8d69840ab 2020-05-04)

Code:

```
use async_std::task;

// This is sync code.
fn main() {
    task::block_on(foo());
}

// This is async code.
async fn foo() {
    println!("aaa");
}
```

[image: error message print screen]

Comment: Could you please post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Have you installed the source code for the standard library? (`rustup component add rust-src`)

Comment: Yes. I have source code.